# Ubuntu wakes up from sleep but shows black screen instead of login

Tags: drivers, suspend

Laptop: HP Victus 15-fa0xxx (with NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650)

I recently got this laptop and have been dual-booting Ubuntu and Windows 11 on it. While sleep works perfectly fine on Windows 11, sleep simply won't work with Ubuntu. I open the computer from sleep, it flashes the typical Ubuntu text, and then shows a black screen (with the backlight on, I believe).

Assuming this was a problem with the GPU, I've already tried setting the setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` in grub which I found on Ask Ubuntu, but that doesn't do anything. In terms of graphics drivers, I'm using `nvidia-driver-515`. Shut down and log out work fine, I just can't get sleep to work.

My gut instinct tells me it has something to do with the GPU, but I just can't find a solution to the problem.

Comment: Have you tried changing the kernel?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I thought it was the graphics card... It was the Intel processor.

I made a step-by-step tutorial on Github: [click here for step-by-step guide with images and more info](https://github.com/Linux-Alex/HP-Victus-Linux-sleep-mode-hibernation) and also a short guide here:

### Solution

To resolve the issue, follow these steps:

1. Install the `nvidia-driver-535` (proprietary, tested).
2. Edit the `/etc/default/grub` file.

   Change: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`

   To: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="intel_idle.max_cstate=4"`
3. Run: `sudo update-grub`

That did the trick for me. Hope it also worked for you.